# Best way to run powershell script on multiple machines

Tags: powershell

This is my first question in SO.

I am creating a script to get the disk space details from multiple machines at regular interval. Script can be run by schedule task using bat file.

I don't want to use any credentials in schedule task as it is against our security policy.

I am not sure what is the best way to run this script on multiple machines.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you searched for a solution?  Please post what you have tried along with any error messages and we'll help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am able to run script on local machine. It is working fine if i run it manually. i want to run it by schedule task. I just want want to know how can i accomplish this.

Comment: I searched on google and tried to search in SO as well. But i didn't found relevant answer. However, you guys are more experience than me. So, anyone from here can help. I hope.

Comment: GPO startup script? Scheduled task using System account?

Comment: PowerShell `Register-ScheduledJob` there are numerous ways in the Windows world to schedule things.  We only say this because ultimately  you know what works for you and we don't want to guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i will check.

Comment: This is basically an infrastructure administration question, not a question about a programming topic, so it should rather be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Do i need to ask it there or it can be migrated?

Comment: Moderators might be able to migrate it, but it'd be simpler if you just deleted it here and re-posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

DOS Batch, [FOR command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) run command on multiple machines.

```
for /f ["options"] %a in (list.txt) DO BatchFile.CMD %a
```

Or use [Sysinternals PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to execute a batch file on multiple servers.

```
PSEXEC list.txt -s BatchFile.cmd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what i am looking for.